# Get current value in a set of CSS classes using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have some class like this

```
<div class = "student">
<div class = "name">Adam </div>
<input class = "paperTaken">
</div>

<div class = "student">
<div class = "name">Smith</div>
<input class = "paperTaken">
</div>
```

When I put the cusor on an input field (say, "paperTaken" in the first "student" class), I can get the corresponding value in class "name" (eg: Adam).

Could you help me?
Thank you in advance.

P/S:

Actually I used it for autoComplete with the [Jquery Autocomplete Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) , so I must listen to paperTaken for autocomplete

```
$(function(){ 
autoComplete(); 
} 

function autoComplete() { 
//This will result list of papers that StudentName take 
$(".paperTaken").autocomplete(baseUrl+"/autocomplete.php?student=StudentName 
... }
```

I want to get the student name to put into the request for autocomplete. 
So I tried to apply your suggestion using

```
$('.paperTaken').focus(function() {
 ... 
}
```

But it's seem that not work.

I'm wondering if the "papertaken" was already listened by autocomplete, can it listen to the "focus" call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to fill the input with the content of the element with class `name`? Then following might work (untested):

```
$('.paperTaken').focus(function(){
  $(this).val($(this).siblings('.name').text());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the following:
$('.paperTaken').focus(function(){
  $("Test").html($(this).siblings('.name').text());
});
But don't return to any result.
I've edited my question to clarify the purpose. Can you review and help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.paperTaken').focus(function() {
       // $(this) references the <input> element that received focus
       // .prev() references the sibling that comes directly before $(this)
       // .text() will return the text value of the .prev() element
    var name = $(this).prev().text();

      // Log the result to the console, or use it however you need
    console.log( name );
});
```

---

**Relevant jQuery docs:**

- `.prev()` - http://api.jquery.com/prev/
- `.text()` - http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

1. List item

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('input.paperTaken').focus(function() {
        var value=$(this).siblings('.name').text();
        $(this).val(value);
    });
```

});